# iOS Keyboard in Native Web

Tags: ios, html, web, keyboard, native

I am creating a app using HTML5,CSS, jQuerymobile + Phonegap.

I want to remove the top section of the Keyboard which has the default - Previous/Next Autofill, Done

Example: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC587100.png

Can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a plugin in phonegap to create native `UITextField`s at the specified position.

Comment: Can we do something in the jQuery/HTML5 side of it? Before bringing it in Phonegap?